# System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException after I migrated to net5.0 from netcore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, nullable-reference-types, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

I'm getting this error on one of my fetch services

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException
> HResult=0x80131931
> Message=Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null
> values.   Source=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> Infrastructure.Data.Repository.Base.EfRepository`1.List(ISpecification`1
> spec) in C:\mydir\master\src\DataTier\SMYLS.Data.Respository\Repository\Base\EfRepository.cs:line
> 88    at
> ApplicationCore.Services.Items.ItemService.SearchItems(ItemSearchDataModel
> searchModel) in C:\mydir\master\src\ServiceTier\SMYLS.Services\Items\ItemService.cs:line 202    at
> Web.Controllers.Api.InvoiceController.GetItemList(ItemSearchDataModel
> searchModel) in C:\mydir\master\src\Web\Controllers\Api\InvoiceController.cs:line 322    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> [External Code]
> Infrastructure.Data.Repository.Base.EfRepository.List(ApplicationCore.Interfaces.Repository.ISpecification)
> in EfRepository.cs
> ApplicationCore.Services.Items.ItemService.SearchItems(ApplicationCore.DTOs.Items.ItemSearchDataModel)
> in ItemService.cs
> Web.Controllers.Api.InvoiceController.GetItemList(ApplicationCore.DTOs.Items.ItemSearchDataModel)
> in InvoiceController.cs
> [External Code]

This happened after I migrated to net5.0. If I run my netcore3.1, there's no problem at all.
I've researched this error and mostly found errors that were caused when your model is expecting a required property but the database returns a null value. I checked my models but they seem fine (they work on 3.1 without any issue)

these are my model properties

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; }
public DateTime UpdatedDateUtc { get; set; }
public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
public int ClinicId { get; set; }
public int? ServiceGroupId {get;set;}
public string ShortCode { get; set; }
public int? IndustryCodeId { get; set; }
public bool Subscription { get; set; }
public bool BlockBill { get; set; }
public decimal? DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
#nullable enable
public string? SubscriptionType { get; set; }
public virtual Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
public virtual SiteUser UpdatedByNavigation { get; set; }
public virtual ServiceGroup ServiceGroup { get; set; }
public virtual IndustryCode IndustryCode { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItem { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<DoctorPricing> DoctorPricing { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<DoctorPricingHistory> DoctorPricingHistory { get; set; }
```

And these are my sample data from db
[image]

Still can't figure out why this is not working in net5.0

Comment: Should the `ServiceGroup`‘s property have a return type of `ServiceGroup?`, to account for the nullable column `ServiceGroupId`?

Comment: @JeremyCaney wow you're right. What you said is exactly what solved the error. I've been debugging this for days now. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, wow, glad to hear! Sometimes it just requires that extra set of eyes. I’ve formalized my comment as an answer, though I’m not able to give a definitive answer as to _why_ ASP.NET Core is okay with your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On quick glance, I’d suspect the `ServiceGroup` property, which has a return type of `ServiceGroup`, but corresponds to a nullable `ServiceGroupId` column in the database. I’d expect that the return type of the property would need to be `ServiceGroup?` to allow for nulls.

I’m not certain why that wasn’t throwing an exception in ASP.NET Core 3.x. My suspicion is that ASP.NET Core 5.x does a better job of enforcing nullability of reference types at runtime, thus raising awareness of a long-standing discrepancy in the data model.